Send Data Fom Fragment to Activity Kotlin
I am building a calculator application in which buttons section is inside fragment (fragment belongs to main_activity only) and result textview is in main_activity.
Now can anyone tell a simple procedure for button click listener, how to write kotlin code i.e.,
when I press a button which is inside the fragment, the text of the button should display in the textview of the activty.
Helpme guys...
One more thing, also tell me is it possible to swipe layouts (i.e., L.Layot) using viewpager2.
Help me guys.

This question is similar to: Passing Data Between Fragments to Activity. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can achieve this by using interface for communication between your Activity and Fragment.
1-Create a Interface in your Fragment
class ButtonFragment : Fragment() {

    private var listener: OnButtonClickListener? = null
    private var bidding: FragmentButtonBinding? = null

    interface OnButtonClickListener {
        fun onButtonClicked(text: String)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is OnButtonClickListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException("$context must implement OnButtonClickListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        bidding = FragmentButtonBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.onButtonClicked(binding.button.text.toString())
        }

        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    }
}

2- Listening in Activity
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ButtonFragment.OnButtonClickListener {

    private var resultTextView: TextView? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        resultTextView = findViewById(R.id.resultText)

        val fragment = ButtonFragment()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)  // fragment container is the frame layout
            .commit()
    }

    override fun onButtonClicked(text: String) {
        // update textview with the button text
        resultTextView?.text = text
    }
}

Yes, you can swipe layout using ViewPager2

Add ViewPager2 to your activity/fragment
Create a Adapter that hold the fragments

